# Append text after a variable in sed

Tags: bash, sed, gnu-parallel

I have some code using GNU-parallel which should replace text in an input file with a series of strings of the form `vclist_2d_*.txt` where `*` is a number between 1 and 10000.

```
FILES=(vclist_2d_*.txt)

parallel -j1  '
    sed -i "s/50pc\/vclist_2d_.*/50pc\/{}'\''/" 1759_input.py
    sed -i "s/schedule_analysis\/vclist_2d_.*/schedule_analysis\/{}'\\_temp\/1759_cs_output.spc''\''/" 1759_input.py
       ' ::: ${FILES[@]}
```

The first `sed` command successful replaces whichever `vclist_2d_*` file is already in `1759_input` with the next one in the list `FILES` as defined by `{}`. However, the second `sed` command needs to replace the `vclist_2d_*` and append to this the text `_temp/1759_cs_output.spc'`

However, with the code above two things happen:

1. the `vclist` name never gets replaced with the next one in the list
2. the text `.temp/1759_cs_output.spc` gets appended rather than `_temp/1759_cs_output.spc`

I've tried several variations of the above none of which were successful. I'm not sure why this works successfully for the first `sed` but not the second. I thought maybe `_` needed escaping but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're doing with the single quotes: I am going to assume that your regex pattern is too greedy and you need to add a quote that got consumed. I'll change `.*` to `[^']0` -- i.e. zero or more non-quote characters.

You're doing twice as much work as required: put both substitutions into a single sed call

```
parallel -j1  ' 
    sed -i "
        s@\(50pc\)/vclist_2d_[^'\'']*@\1/{}@
        s@\(schedule_analysis\)/vclist_2d_[^'\'']*@\1/{}_temp/1759_cs_output.spc@
    " 1759_input.py
' ::: "${FILES[@]}"
```

I used a different delimiter for the `s///` command in order to reduce backslashes

Comment: You are entering quoting hell. Consider using a bash function or at least -q.

Comment: Glenn, the single quotes are there because the sed function is stripping a quote off the end; the file this is working on is a python input file and the text is a string python is interpreting.

Comment: Could you explain what the @s are doing?

Comment: The @s are used for `s@@@` instead of `s///`. I do that so I don't have to escape the /s in the path.